# Google SketchUp network licensing issue

Tags: license, sketchup

We have 10 licenses for Google SketchUp in my local office.  We store the license file on a network drive that is accessible to all users.  We've been finding that, at most, only 3 or 4 people can run it at one time before the license shows up as "expired" on another user's system.  I've verified with Google that we have 10 licenses, and have downloaded updated license files from them.

The only thing that I can think of is that sometimes SketchUp crashes.  Could this be utilizing a license somehow without giving it up?  Google has not been able to answer this question.

Comment: Is the date+time correct on all the computers? Can all users/computers access the network drive at the same time?

Comment: @Chris - Yes to both questions.  I found [this link](http://sketchup.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=65650) on Google's SU support pages, but it doesn't really explain what causes the issue, and the "resolve" is what I've already been doing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to use a mapped network drive or a UNC path for the license file:

Perform these steps in a VM where UAC is disabled.

1. Create a share from a local folder or drive
2. Install SketchUp wit hall default settings
3. Start Sketchup as Admin
4. Click “Start using SketchUp” (Select a Template:  Simple Template – meters)
5. Click Help -> License -> Authorize
6. Click Skip, enter your license information and click OK
7. Browse to the share created at step 1 and click OK

SketchUp is now activated and a server.dat file (with a reference to the license file) has been created in C:\ProgramData\SketchUp\SketchUp 2014

8. The license file itself can be found in the chosen share from step 1
   This license file can be moved to a mapped network drive or UNC-path
9. Remove the created share if needed

**Attention!** The server.dat file contains a reference to the license file. This reference should be changed to the path where you store the license file itself, may it be on a mapped network drive or UNC path. The server.dat file can be copied to all systems using SketchUp. Mind you that the server.dat file can only be edited with an advanced editor like NotePad++ else it will not work!!

So you can use \server\share or X:\share